# WPF - Hyperlink style does not change with the style of label inside

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, label, styles

Given the following XAML markup, I would expect the text in the Hyperlink to turn orange when I mouse over it, since I am setting a foreground colour on its parent control and it should filter down by [Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx). Yet it stays black. What do I need to do?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DemoLink" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource DemoLink}">
                <Label Content="Text that should change colour on mouse over" />
            </Hyperlink>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Update:** The simple answer from Meleak is that using a TextBlock instead of the inner Label causes the style to work as expected - the TextBlock picks up the foreground colour from its parent, while the Label does not.

e.g.

```
<Label>
    <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource DemoLink}">
        <TextBlock Text="Text that does change colour on mouse over" />
    </Hyperlink>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Label` isn't affected by `Foreground` set on its parent. Even this has no effect

```
<Label>
    <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource DemoLink}" Foreground="DarkOrange">
        <Label Content="This is some text that should change colour on mouse over" />
    </Hyperlink>
</Label>
```

**Update**
Set a Style for the `Label` instead of the `Hyperlink` and it'll work

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DemoLinkLabel" TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label>
        <Hyperlink Name="DemoHyperlink" >
            <Label Content="This is some text that should change colour on mouse over"
                   Style="{StaticResource DemoLinkLabel}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

**Update again**
The easy way is to use a `TextBlock` instead of `Label` since it doesn't have this problem

```
<Hyperlink Name="DemoHyperlink" Style="{StaticResource DemoLink}">
    <TextBlock Text="This is some text that should change colour on mouse over"/>
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: that works, but I'm not happy with it. What if there were two labels in the hyperlink? Mousing over any part of the hyperlink should set the colour on all of it.

Comment: @Anthony. Found the problem. In the default Style for `Label`, the Foreground is set to <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>. I'll try to come up with a workaround for it

Comment: @Anthony: I updated my answer with using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`. Do you have to use a `Label`?

Answer (score 3):

@Fredrik explained well above. So here can be a simple style and Hyperlink usage

You should build your Hyperlink like this

```
<TextBlock Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Hyperlink Click="ForgotPassword_Clicked">
        <TextBlock Text="Forgot Password?"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

And then this style should work for you with normal and hover styles

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This gave me exactly the solution that I was looking for, well without the red foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the style for hyperlink, not the label. You need to set the same trigger for a label, so it can also react to IsMouseOver event.

Comment: Yes, I have set the style for hyperlink, not the label. The label does not have a foreground explicitly set, so it should get that value from its parent as per Property Inheritance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx I want all content in the hyperlink to get that forground set. But it does not.

Comment: Not every Dependency Property participates in value inheritance. Hyperlink, I believe is one that doesn't. I can see that you found solution with TextBlock but I can mention just one more way to do it. You can just write: <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource DemoLink}">
                This is some text that should change colour on mouse over
            </Hyperlink>

Comment: If Hyperlinks don't participate in value inheritance, then how is the Foreground property being passed down from the Hyperlink to the textBlock? It seems more likely that the Label.Foreground property doesn't get an inherited value, because it is being explicitly set by the default style for labels and this takes precedence, as Meleak said.